# iOS revoke location services permission programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Is there a function on `CLLocationManager` or `UIApplication` to revoke location permission that is similar to the function `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` to revoke the push notification permission?

The `stopUpdatingLocation` function on CLLocation does not revoke the permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a user has granted (or denied) location permissions by responding to the original permission request dialog, the only way that the permissions can be changed is by the user themselves using the device settings app.

You can just not use location services even though your app still has permission to do so.

Comment: Makes sense to me now, thanks. Your last sentence is a little confusing though.